# grouping rows in mantine table in react: Encountered two children with the same key error

Tags: reactjs, grouping, mantine

[enter image description here][1]I'm trying to group the rows in the mantine table and this is what I've tried
I'm new to mantine and react and
I'm trying to group the rows in the mantine table here but I came up with this error
output I'm trying to achieve should be like this: https://muptr.csb.app/

```
import { Table } from "@mantine/core";
export const Demo = () => {
  let sameKey: string;
  const column = [
    {
      title: "District",
      dataIndex: "state_name",
      key: "state_name",
      render: (value: string) => {
        const obj = {
          children: value,
          props: {} as { rowSpan: number },
        };
        if (!(sameKey !== value)) {
          obj.props.rowSpan = 0;
          return obj;
        }
        const count = data.filter((item) => item.state_name === value).length;
        sameKey = value;
        obj.props.rowSpan = count;
        return obj;
      },
    },
    {
      title: "Exam Details",
      children: [
        {
          title: "Gender Details",
          dataIndex: "gender",
          key: 1,
        },
        {
          title: "Total number of candidates",
          dataIndex: "total",
          key: 2,
        },
        {
          title: "Total Number of candidates passed",
          dataIndex: "passed_total",
          key: 3,
        },
      ],
    },
  ];
  const data = [
    {
      state_name: "Karnataka",
      gender: "Boys",
      total: Math.floor(Math.random() * 90 + 10),
      passed_total: Math.floor(Math.random() * 90 + 10),
    },
    {
      state_name: "Karnataka",
      gender: "Girls",
      total: Math.floor(Math.random() * 90 + 10),
      passed_total: Math.floor(Math.random() * 90 + 10),
    },
    {
      state_name: "Karnataka",
      gender: "Transgender",
      total: Math.floor(Math.random() * 90 + 10),
      passed_total: Math.floor(Math.random() * 90 + 10),
    },
    {
      state_name: "Kerala",
      gender: "Boys",
      total: Math.floor(Math.random() * 90 + 10),
      passed_total: Math.floor(Math.random() * 90 + 10),
    },
    {
      state_name: "Kerala",
      gender: "Girls",
      total: Math.floor(Math.random() * 90 + 10),
      passed_total: Math.floor(Math.random() * 90 + 10),
    },
    {
      state_name: "Tamilnadu",
      gender: "Boys",
      total: Math.floor(Math.random() * 90 + 10),
      passed_total: Math.floor(Math.random() * 90 + 10),
    },
    {
      state_name: "Tamilnadu",
      gender: "Girls",
      total: Math.floor(Math.random() * 90 + 10),
      passed_total: Math.floor(Math.random() * 90 + 10),
    },
    {
      state_name: "Andhra Pradesh",
      gender: "Boys",
      total: Math.floor(Math.random() * 90 + 10),
      passed_total: Math.floor(Math.random() * 90 + 10),
    },
  ];
  return (
    <Table withBorder withColumnBorders style={{ width: "50%", margin: "0 auto", marginTop: "50px" }}>
      <thead>
        {column.map((d) => (
          <>
            <tr>
              <th>{d.children?.[0].title}</th>
              <th>{d.children?.[1].title}</th>
              <th>{d.children?.[2].title}</th>
            </tr>
          </>
        ))}
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {data.map((d) => (
          <>
            <tr>
              <td key={d.state_name}>{d.gender}</td>
              <td key={d.state_name}>{d.total}</td>
              <td key={d.state_name}>{d.passed_total}</td>
            </tr>
          </>
        ))}
      </tbody>
    </Table>
  );
};
```

I'm new to mantine and react and
I'm trying to group the rows in the mantine table here but I came up with this error
output I'm trying to achieve should be like this: https://muptr.csb.app/
`

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iYvv5.png this is what im getting as output

Comment: Can you please elaborate the error

Comment: arning: Encountered two children with the same key, `Karnataka`. Keys should be unique so that components maintain their identity across updates. Non-unique keys may cause children to be duplicated and/or omitted — the behavior is unsupported and could change in a future version.

Answer (score 0):

add keys on  tags

```
 {column.map((d,idx) => (
      
        <tr key={idx}>
          <th>{d.children?.[0].title}</th>
          <th>{d.children?.[1].title}</th>
          <th>{d.children?.[2].title}</th>
        </tr>
      
    ))}


 {data.map((d,idx) => (

        <tr key={idx}>
          <td key={d.state_name}>{d.gender}</td>
          <td key={d.state_name}>{d.total}</td>
          <td key={d.state_name}>{d.passed_total}</td>
        </tr>

    ))}
```